# How to use EM_CHARFROMPOS with RichTextBox in C#

Tags: c#, winapi, richtextbox

I am trying to use following code to retrieve character index by position in a *RichTextBox*. I know I can use *GetCharIndexFromPosition* method provided by *RichTextBox* Class, but I want to know what is wrong with following code:

*SendMessage* import is this:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage", CharSet= CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, ref POINTL lParam);
```

And then this call:

```
int returnVal = (int)WinUser.SendMessage(this._textBox.Handle, (int)WinUser.Message.EM_CHARFROMPOS, 0, ref p);
```

where **p** is the *POINTL stucture* instance containing the screen coordinates with upper-left corner of *RichTextBox* as origin.

The *POINTL Structure* is defined as

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct POINTL
{
    public long x;
    public long y;
}
```

The *POINTL* **p** has been initialized as:

```
WinUser.POINTL p;
p.x = 0;
p.y = 0;
```

NOW THE PROBLEM:

If **p** is initialized as given above the *returnVal* is 0

If **p** is anything else like {*x* = 10, *y* =10} or {*x* = 1 and *y* = 1} the *returnVal* is 1

In both the cases the function *GetCharIndexFromPosition* gives the correct index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `long` to `int`.
(Win32 `LONG`s are 32-bit integers that correspond to .Net `int`s)

.Net's `GetCharIndexFromPosition` method is defined as

```
    public override int GetCharIndexFromPosition(Point pt) { 
        NativeMethods.POINT wpt = new NativeMethods.POINT(pt.X, pt.Y);
        int index = (int)UnsafeNativeMethods.SendMessage(new HandleRef(this, Handle), NativeMethods.EM_CHARFROMPOS, 0, wpt); 

        string t = this.Text;
        // EM_CHARFROMPOS will return an invalid number if the last character in the RichEdit
        // is a newline. 
        //
        if (index >= t.Length) { 
            index = Math.Max(t.Length - 1, 0); 
        }
        return index; 
    }
```

The `NativeMethods.POINT` type is defined as

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)] 
    public class POINT {
        public int x; 
        public int y; 

        public POINT() { 
        }

        public POINT(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x; 
            this.y = y;
        } 

#if DEBUG
        public override string ToString() { 
            return "{x=" + x + ", y=" + y + "}";
        }
#endif
    }
```

Comment: This worked. How can I look at actual implementation of functions in .NET . Like the one you have given here?